# Нет вертикальной полосы прокрутки

Tags: css

Здравствуйте! У меня есть каталог организаций, я вывожу его в 3 колонки.
При разрешении 1920 x 1080 есть вертикальная полоса прокрутки, а при 1024 х 600 она отсутствует! Как включить отображение?

Скрин 1024 х 600:

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рабочий пример на **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ga77H/)**

```
height: 100px; /* Должна быть задана высота блока */
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
height: 550px;  
overflow: auto;
```

Comment: поставил к body, так и нет результата